# Ant to Gradle Build Project - Help/Assistance Needed

Tags: gradle, ant, build-automation

Nice to be in this channel.
I have a specific need that I'm hoping some of you might be able to help with.
We have a large project where we are migrating from ant to Gradle. The Java code has been built up over the past 15 years so there is a lot of it.
We are struggling with this migration as we don't know gradle at a deep level. We know how it works & have used it lots of times to build java projects. However, this is different as the projects are so large, we need somebody with a deep understanding of how gradle works at a low level.
So, I'm putting this message out there, asking if anybody is interested in working with us on this for 3,6,9+ months. If you know of anybody who could help us then I would really appreciate an intro.
Thanks in advance, John.

Comment: Happy to get help on a 3,6+ month contract if that helps